# How to obtain a P-Value from a Python Scipy Optimize Least Squares regression?

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, p-value, chi-squared

I have performed a function minimization using Python `scipy.optimize.least_squares`.

The function minimized is a chi-squared function.

```
solution = scipy.optimize.least_squares(optimize_function, x0, method='lm', \
        ftol=1.0e-8, xtol=1.0e-8, \
        max_nfev=1000000, args=(bin_midpoints, hist_data))
```

The residuals can be obtianed via `solution.fun`. Calculating the chi-squared value using the residuals leads to the same result as

```
2.0 * solution.cost
```

As a next step, I am trying to calculate a P-Value from this chi-square value.

In similar libraries which I have used previously, the "p-value" is typically provided somewhere in the output.

Looking at the docs, I don't see anything obvious which might be a P-Value in the value returned by `least_squares`.

Do I have to calculate it manually, perhaps using some other Python library?

Comment: I don't see how it could calculate a p-value. Libraries which can calculate this generally require that coefficients are linearly multiplied with covariates. `least_squares()` has no such requirement, and allows the fitting of non-linear functions. Given the amount of work in calculating the p-value yourself, I would use a different library, like statsmodels.

Comment: @NickODell I think if I understand correctly, strictly speaking one would require that the uncertainties/errors be gaussian distributed (the residuals are gaussian distributed) and that the problem is a linear regression model. However, there are other numerical fitting libraries which (presumably) assume the model is linear in the region of the best fit minimum, and can calculate a p-value. CERN Root is one such example. (It is a C++ library.) Can you explain your suggestion in using statsmodels?

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to read up on that. My suggestion with statsmodels is that you use one of the regressions in that package, such as OLS, and fit it to your data. Statsmodels can then give you a p-value from that. https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/regression.html That may be a non-starter if you are doing non-linear regression. Is your regression linear? Keep in mind that even something like `Y = beta0 + beta1*X**2 + epsilon` is linear if you transform X before fitting the regression.

Comment: No my regression is not linear and actually I am doing a bad thing by using this instead of a maximum likelihood, because I am fitting a gaussian model to histogram data, where I expect the number of events in each bin to (probably) follow a Poisson distribution. Since asking this question I implemented a maximum likelihood method, but this is besides the point.

Comment: If the issue is just that it's a Poisson distribution, could you use GLM with family/link function set to Poisson? E.g. https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/glm.html

Comment: @NickODell I would have to understand in detail what GLM are in order to answer that question unfortunatly as I am not familiar with this area. I will endevour to do some research on this early next week